# Socket connection coming from LAN?

Tags: python, .net, sockets, tcp, lan

Is there a way to check if an incoming connection on a TCP socket is coming from a LAN or not?

I'm currently checking the incoming address and seeing if it resides in the private network range (192.168.x.x/10.x.x.x etc)

Is there a better way to do it?

I'm particularly interested in solutions in Python and .NET if that helps.

Comment: What you want to do with that would be more important? Are you already checking programmatically? then what's missing?

Comment: What have you tried so far?...Have you thought about using `regex` for starter?...

Comment: I was wondering if there was a better way to do it besides IP matching?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm on the right track with this.  Will continue along this route